# Apply style to a specific set of keywords in a post?

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I'd like to apply some style to any instances of a specific set of words in a post. Such as names, places, etc.

I believe this is sufficiently different to syntax highlighting that would only apply to a code block.

So, in my post front matter I would have:

`keywords: [Deneba, Star Wars, Han Solo, Obiwan]`

and in the rendered Post I would like to see:

> *Han Solo* was on his way to *Deneba* with *Obiwan*.
> — Excerpt from *Star Wars*

I'm hosting on GitHub Pages, but can change that if I need to.

Thoughts appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hacked this together:

```
{% assign modified = content %}
{% for noun in page.nouns %}
{% assign italic = noun | prepend: '<em>' | append: '</em>' %}
{% assign modified = modified | replace: noun,italic %}
{% endfor %}
{{ modified }}
```